# Updating one of the Formik initial values with state resets all other values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I currently have a form I am building using formik.  I am able to update each of the fields(name, email, phone) as expected. The issue I am running into is when I provide one of the formik intial values with a state value and update that state.  The act of updating the state causes the form to completely reset the input fields Is there a way to update the test state without resetting the entire form?? My code is as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, FieldArray } from "formik";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={{
        test: test,
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: ""
      }}
    >
      {({
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit
      }) => (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => setTest("something")}>Update State</button>
          <br />
          <input
            placeholder="name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            placeholder="email"
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            placeholder="phone"
            type="text"
            name="phone"
            value={values.phone}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <>
            <pre style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
              <strong>Values</strong>
              <br />
              {JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}
            </pre>
            <pre style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
              <strong>Errors</strong>
              <br />
              {JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2)}
            </pre>
          </>
        </>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

In order to replicate what I am talking about in the codesandbox first update the name, email, and phone number.  Then hit the udate state button and everything will be reset

codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-sun-mzeuy?file=/src/App.js:0-1567

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you are initializing the Formik component with [`enableReinitialize`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) set to `true`:

> `enableReinitialize?: boolean`
>
> Default is false. Control whether Formik should reset the form if initialValues changes (using deep equality).

When the state variable `test` is updated, the formik-values are reinitialized to the values set in `initialValues`.

---

If you want this to work, I've [forked your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-butterfly-vhfv1?file=/src/App.js) and modified it to use the formik hook (without `enableReinitialize`) in combination with a `useEffect` to  manually update the value from state:

```js
  const [test, setTest] = useState(null);
  const { values, errors, handleChange, setFieldValue } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      test: test,
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setFieldValue("test", test);
  }, [test]);
```

Comment: yes I understand this much, Im just curious if there is a way to update the test state value whithout the other values resetting

Comment: I've added a modified example of your sandbox with `useFormik` in combination with a `useEffect` to update the `test` field value.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was to use the Formik values as state and set it directly with `setFieldValue`, so `enableInitialize` would not be triggered.

```
export default function App() {
  //const [test, setTest] = useState(null); // This removed
  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={{
        test: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: ""
      }}
    >
```

...

```
 <button onClick={() => setFieldValue("test", "something")}>Update State</button>
```

Mostly the reason you would want to use states outside of Formik is to use it outside of Formik (ok clear), but this way you still can trigger a function from outside of Formik which you pass the `values` and the `setFieldValue`- Function to do whatever when triggered e.g. at `onChange` of a Formik field:

```
  const handlerDefinedOutside = (values: any, setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void): void => { /* do stuff */ };

  <TextField
     onChange={(e) => {
       handleChange(e);
       handlerDefinedOutside(values, setFieldValue);
     }}
  />
```